# Delete nested obejct property by "path" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
var test = {
    foo: {
        bar: {
            qwe: 123,
            abc: ['x','y','z']
        }
    }
};
```

I would like to be able to dynamically delete any property I want using an array representing the "path" if you will.

Let me explain:

```
deleteProp(test,['foo','bar','qwe']);
```

should delete `test.foo.bar.qwe`. Just like `delete test.foo.bar.qwe;` would.

This is what I've tried:

```
function deleteProp(obj, pathSegments) {
    let lastSubObj = obj
    pathSegments.forEach((segment,i)=>{
        lastSubObj = lastSubObj[segment] = (i === pathSegments.length-1) ? undefined : {};
    });
    lastSubObj = undefined;
    return obj;
}
```

But it results in:

```
{
    foo: {
        bar: {
            qwe: undefined
        }
    }
}
```

So the property is not actually deleted and in addition to that the `abc` property is gone now.

Comment: Why don't you use `delete` instead of setting to `undefined`?

Comment: Because I don't see how this would work. Feel free to post an answer though.

Comment: You've got a good answer from Nina. I think you were confused between deleting an object (setting it to undefined) and deleting a property.

Comment: I know that I just set it to undefined. But how am I supposed to use `delete` when all I have is a base object and a variable containing a reference to the nested property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could reduce the object by walking the path. Before walking save the last property as key for deleting the object.

The callback uses a default object if a property is not in the object.

```js
function deleteProp(object, path) {
    var last = path.pop();
    delete path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] || {}, object)[last];
}

var test = { foo: { bar: { qwe: 123, abc: ['x','y','z'] } } };

deleteProp(test, ['foo', 'bar', 'qwe']);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your are using lastSubObj = undefined:

Use `youObject.foo.bar['lastSubObj']`

Comment: This does not fix the issue. NinaScholz's answer is the correct one.